# Freyd non-concreteness in motivic homotopy theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

The following theorem is due to Freyd.

> Let $C$ be a category of pointed topological spaces including all finite-dimensional CW-complexes. Let $H:C\to \mathrm{Set}$ be a homotopy invariant functor. There exists $f:X\to Y$ such that $f$ is not null-homotopic but $H(f)=H(\star)$ where $\star$ is null-homotopic.

Is there an analogue of this theorem in motivic homotopy theory?

Comment: There is a canonical "constant sheaf functor" from the homotopy category of CW-complexes to the homotopy category of motivic spaces over a base field $k$. For $k=\mathbb{C}$, there is a Betti realization functor, the composition of which with the constant sheaf functor is the identity. Therefore, the constant sheaf functor is then a faithful embedding of CW-complexes up to homotopy in motivic spaces, and any embedding of motivic spaces over $\mathbb{C}$ in sets would thus provide an embedding of CW-complexes up to homotopy in sets, contradicting Freyd's theorem.

Comment: di Liberti and Loregian observed that Freyd essentially shows that if there is a faithful functor $Ab \to \mathcal C$ where $\mathcal C$ is stable / triangulated, then $\mathcal C$ is not concrete.I think there is a faithful functor $Ab \to \mathcal C$ when $\mathcal C$ is the stable motivic category over any non-empty scheme. So such a $\mathcal C$ is never concrete. In forthcoming work, I plan to show that $\mathcal D(QCoh(X))$ is concrete if and only if every stalk of $\mathcal O_X$ is a field. In particular, $\mathcal D(R)$ is concerete (for $R$ commutative) iff $R$ is von Neumann regular.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain that there is a faithful functor $Ab \to \mathcal C$ when $\mathcal C$ is the stable motivic category over $\mathbb F_p$ (but surely the answer is clear to anybody who knows the first thing about motivic homotopy theory!). But to run Freyd's construction, it would suffice to have a faithful functor $Mod_{\mathbb Z_{(p)}} \to \mathcal C$, which I'm more confident exists in this case.